# Error for x in range: TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run a program in which the user types two words and I have to find the last letter of that word. After that, I have to find out if that letter is in the second word. I started of like this:

```
x=input('Type a word')
y=input('Type another word')
for x in range:
    print (x[-1])
```

Comment: You are trying to iterate over reference to __range__ function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = raw_input('Type a word')
y = raw_input('Type another word')


if x:
    print x[-1] in y
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because you cannot iterate over a non generator function instance...

A better and more pythonic way to achieve what your trying to do would be:

```
x=input('Type a word')
y=input('Type another word')

if x[-1] in y:
    print('its there alright :)')
```